# What is a idiom for a person who can read people and is perceptive?

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm doing homework and I need idiom for a character who is very perceptive?

Comment: 'Emotional intelligence'

Comment: They have a high EQ - Emotional quotient. It also means that they adapt and respond in a socially acceptable manner.

Answer (score 2):

Try [***have good antennae***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&lr=lang_en&biw=710&bih=466&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22have+good+antennae%22&oq=%22have+good+antennae%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...7829.9043.0.9856.6.6.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..6.0.0.27DAi_Lbo_w)

> To be very sensitive (to something); to have a keen sense of detection or perception. Likened to the antennae of (e.g.) an insect, which are extremely sensitive to environmental stimuli. *The best teacher must have good antennae for any emotional difficulties their students may be going through.*
>
> [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/antenna)
>
> *There are a few who master all the skills, but there is none who lacks the most necessary attribute of all: good antennae. I've got them. I can usually sense a problem a mile away.*
>
> [Willful Blindness](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22good+antennae%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=PlQsV6y1H4TwaI2_sOAB)

Also, ***have a [keen/good] [eye for reading people](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=1024&bih=672&tbm=bks&q=%22eye+for+reading+people%22&oq=%22eye+for+reading+people%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...7071.9067.0.9798.5.5.0.0.0.0.333.635.3-2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..3.1.332...30i10.vdf1iwy4wVE)***

> have an eye for something
>
> Be discriminating or perceptive about something [c. 1700 ]
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/have--an--eye--for)
>
> *Herb Pratt is a true American salesman, with an eye for reading people.*
>
> [Bold Consulting & Training](http://www.boldconsultingandtraining.com/about-us/)

Answer (score 1):

Try [have/keep your ear to the ground](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-keep-your-ear-to-the-ground). It means someone who is very perceptive, attentive to everything people say or do.

Google it and see for yourself.

Another good idiom is [be on the ball](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-on-the-ball). It means to keep your finger on the pulse or keep/have your wits about you. In other words, it means attentive and perceptive.

Google these too.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that a person **[doesn't miss much](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+miss+much)** or that **[nothing](http://www.english-idioms-and-expressions.com/common-idioms.html)** or **not much gets past** them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a highfalutin word, *[perspicacious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/perspicacious)*

> Having a ready insight into and understanding of things:
>   *it offers quite a few facts to the perspicacious reporter*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*